# Perl HTTP::Recorder Module Throws Content Encoding Error

Tags: perl, http, proxy, recorder

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and am trying to record http requests with perl's HTTP::Recorder module. I am following the instructions here: http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Recorder

I have the following perl script running:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use HTTP::Proxy;
use HTTP::Recorder;

my $proxy = HTTP::Proxy->new();

# create a new HTTP::Recorder object
my $agent = new HTTP::Recorder;

# set the log file (optional)
$agent->file("/tmp/myfile");

# set HTTP::Recorder as the agent for the proxy
$proxy->agent( $agent );

# start the proxy
$proxy->start();
```

And I have changed firefox settings so that it uses port 8080 on the localhost as the proxy. Here is a snapshot of my settings:

[image]

When I try to visit a website with firefox, however, I get the following error:

> Content Encoding Error
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

Not sure what to do. And when I visit:

```
http://http-recorder
```

(Where my recorded activity is supposed to show up) I do see that GET requests are being logged. For example, if I try to visit google:

```
$agent->get('http://www.google.com');
```

Edit: I should also mention that ubuntu is running inside of virtualbox, not sure if that is messing with anything.

Comment: What does the logfile you set up say? Install something like httpfox and check headers and content of the response. Or use curl, wget or lwp-dump to see what is going on.

Comment: Hi innaM, thank you for responding. The logfile shows whatever `http://http-recorder` shows (which is supposed to be the case). So in it, I can see get requests being sent to the sites I am trying to visit. I installed httpfox and checked the headers (http://i.imgur.com/vx0vUZH.png) + content (http://i.imgur.com/P4yh16p.png). So maybe perl is not able to decode gzip encoding?

Comment: Ok, so apparently this module is deprecated: http://search.cpan.org/~semuelf/HTTP-Recorder-0.07/lib/HTTP/Recorder.pm#This_module_is_deprecated So yeah... chased the rabbit down the wrong hole. Going to look into selenium now.

Comment: Haha! Didn't know about the `Server` header reddit.com is sending. Good one!

Comment: I cannot imagine that it's the gzipped content that is causing the error. HTTP::Recorder use HTTP::Proxy which uses LWP::UserAgent which uses HTTP::Response and that one uses  IO::Compress::*